# pandas: получить названия всех листов импортированной из excel таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Как получить названия всех листов импортированной из excel таблицы с помощью pandas? Например у такой таблицы вывести в новый датафрэйм названия листов

link111 = 'https://rosstat.gov.ru/storage/mediabank/ind_10-2022.xlsx'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь классом [ExcelFile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/io.html#excelfile-class):

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile("ind_10-2022.xlsx")
sheet_names = xlsx_file.sheet_names
print(sheet_names)

#df=pd.read_excel(xlsx_file)
#считать в датафрейм можно уже по имени объекта ExcelFile
```

получите список:

> ['Титульный', 'Содержание', 'The Contens', '1.1 ', '1.2', '1.3', '1.4', '1.5 ', '1.6 ', '1.6.1 ', '1.7 ', '1.8 ', '1.9', '1.10', '1.11 ', '1.12 ', '1.13 ', '1.14', '2.1', '2.2 ', '2.3 ', '2.4 ', '2.5 ', '3.1 ', '3.1.1 ', '3.2 ', '3.3 ', '3.4', '3.5 ', '4.1', '4.2 ', '4.3', '4.4 ', '4.5 ', '4.6 (до 2009)', '4.6 (2010-2012)', '4.6 (2013-2022)', '4.7', '4.8 ']
> ​